# How to deal with drain pipe sticking out of bathroom wall

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drywall, framing, drain

This is the picture of a wall behind the toilet. You can see the black pipe sticking out of the drywall about 1"

[image]

[image]

The previous owner decided to build a box around it. I didn't know what was inside and it looks odd so I broke it down. This is the "before" picture:

[image]

So my question is: **Is there a better way to hide this pipe?**

I am thinking:

1. Put back the box with drywall. It was a mistake to remove.
2. Do smaller box around that black pipe only.
3. Paint the pipe white, same wall color, and caulk around the gaps between the pipe and the drywall. Basically it will be a part of the wall.

I prefer Option 3 but I don't know how it would look.

I hate Option 1 though because it is still very obvious (now that I notice) even behind the toilet.

Comment: Not really. How much of an adventure do you want to go on? You could knock all of the walls down and build it differently. you could add a wall (2 sheets of drywall?) but it will shrink the space.You could relocate the pipe.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention. None of those options are possible as I eliminated those options.

Comment: Place an object in front of it, like a toilet perhaps. Sarcasm aside, place an object in front of it. You've pretty much covered or dismissed the things that make the pipe invisible. 1-3 are all possibilities. Other than "buiding a functional thing" in that space thats it.

Comment: There was a toilet in front of it before and it was still obvious.

Comment: Is there a bathroom toilet just above the area where that big black pile goes? This could be a waste line from the upper floor.

Comment: No bathroom directly on top but possible it going down at an angle from about 10ft away upstair.

Comment: Would furring the entire wall out 1”  be a problem?

Comment: @Kris We plan to install tiles so that might be a problem for tiles. Frankly that this point I am thinking about just to put a "access panel door" around that black pipe. I just need something creative...